# how do you parse json files that has incomplete lines in the file?

Tags: json, r

I have bunch of files in one directory that has many entries in the file as this:

```
{"DateTimeStamp":"2017-07-20T21:52:00.767-0400","Host":"Server","Code":"test101","use":"stats"}
```

I need to be able read each file and form a data frame from the json etries. Sometimes, the lines in the file may not be complete and my script is failing. How can I modify this script to account for not complete lines in the files:

```
 path<-c("C:/JsonFiles")



  filenames <- list.files(path, pattern="*Data*", full.names=TRUE)

  dflist <- lapply(filenames, function(i) {
    jsonlite::fromJSON(
      paste0("[",
             paste0(readLines(i),collapse=","),
             "]"),flatten=TRUE
    )
  })

  mq<-rbindlist(dflist, use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: Do you want to disregard files that aren't proper JSON entirely or do you want to try to fix it?

Comment: @ekstroem, I want to be able to disregard json lines that are not complete. Each file contains 1,000's of json formatted entries.